# Cannot apply ??-operator between an ArrayList and an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have code like this:

```
foreach (Type t in types ?? asm.GetTypes())
```

Which should loop all types in the `ArrayList` `types` or the assemblies types if no types are provided. As both `System.Array` as `System.Collections.ArrayList` implement `IEnumerable` I´d expect that loop to work.

However compiler complains:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' and 'System.Type[]'

I suppose I am missing something very obvious, but what is it?

Comment: What is `types`, `asm` and `GetTypes`?

Comment: Should´nt the both return `Type`-instances?

Comment: Why don't you use variables and `if`s: `IEnumerable<Type> typesSeq = types; if(types == null) typesSeq = asm.GetTypes(); foreach(Type t in typesSeq ) ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really use `ArrayList` in 2015. `ArrayList` doesn't support the `IEnumerable<>` interface.

You can force the using of the `IEnumerable` non-generic interface:

```
foreach (Type t in (IEnumerable)types ?? asm.GetTypes())
```

Your error happens because the `??` operator doesn't search for the minimum common type between left and right. It simply checks if right type can be implicitly converted to left type or if left type can be implicitly converted to right type. Clearly `Type[]` can't be converted to `ArrayList` and `ArrayList` can't be converted to `Type[]`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Changed

Answer (score 0):

You can't us the ?? operator on two different structures. Your field 'types' should be a System.Type[] to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely what the reasoning would be but I imagine it is the type safety and that you can add anything to the `ArrayList`.

Consider the [following example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mcrJ2A)

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList{1,2,3};
int[] il = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

Both look very similar, but now lets try adding a list to them.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList{1,2,3, new ArrayList()};  // succeeds
int[] il = new int[]{1,2,3, new ArrayList() };
```

> Compilation error (line 12, col 31): Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'int'

This leads me to believe that the compiler figures that since you are initially hoping to use an arraylist, you aren't guaranteeing that every element will be of type `Type`