# .NET - Adding referenced variable to arraylist vs adding new Object() to ArrayList

Tags: c#

I was just wondering if there are any performance differences (specifically memory usage) when I do the following...

Instead of doing:

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
object obj = new object();

for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    array.Add(obj);
}
```

I do this:

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    array.Add(new object());
}
```

Or is it exactly the same thing?

As I understand it, the system holds a reference to the obj variable in memory, once the method finishes, the variable gets disposed and the memory is freed

So, if I call `ArrayList.Add(new Object())` on each loop, then there is no memory being allocated to a referenced variable?

Comment: Is this Java or C#, answers could very much depend on this fact, its a case of what the object is as to whether you are making 100 different references or the same one

Comment: What would be the difference between Java and C#?

Comment: I think you have to learn more about 'new' keyword.

Comment: Your code will definitely _not_ compile under any Java compiler.  The `List` method is `add()` in lowercase.

Comment: @langjacques - I don't know Java enough to say the difference completely, but most C# answers would say something about why you shouldn't use `ArrayList` for a start

Comment: Sorry guys, I removed the Java and Android tags, this is for C#.

Comment: @Sayse - Do you mean using List<object> obj = new List<object>(); would be the better option than using ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, any `IEnumerable<T>` would be better, it ensures type safety. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30778807/1324033) is just one example of why ArrayLists should be avoided

Comment: @Sayse - How about if you would know the types at runtime, would using an ArrayList be OK (are there any other downsides with using an ArrayList over a List) or should I try to avoid using an ArrayList whenever possible?

Comment: @langjacques - Generally I never find a reason to *not* know the type (always of at least a base class), If I don't know the type then its normally been a design flaw somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one stores the same object reference in all 100 slots of the array.

The second version creates 100 different objects, and store them (the reference to these objects) in the array.

First one: 1 object, 100 references
Second one: 100 objects, 100 references?

It's definitely not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the second approach, in each iteration you are going to instantiate a new object which also needs it's own space in memory. While in the first approach you are referencing always the same object in memory.

So there is a big difference regarding memory allocation. This is with respect to Java and the `add` method starts with a lower case letter. And of course you should parameterize the generic type `ArrayList`.

Comment: not really no, the first approach actually creates new object with a new reference, the only deference is mentioned above.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not really, no'?

Comment: regarding memory allocation it is exactly the same, the 2 approaches have the same effect on memory, both creates new objects.

Comment: The first code snippet creates one object and this object is referenced 100 times. The second snippet creates 100 objects and each one is referenced once. This is what I said in my answer and also what Gosu said. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ahmad - So in other words 100 new objects will be created for both scenarios, however when using the 1st approach all instances references one object where the 2nd approach each have their own instance

Comment: I would not say 100 new objects are created for both scenarios, but each time 100 list elements are creates/used. For the 1st approach they all reference the same and the only `new Object()`, while in the second approach each list element references a unique object.

Answer (score 0):

Extending to Gosu answer, adding the object to array using fist method will not be of any practical use because if you change value of any of the object in array, it will get changed for all 100 item, because of being reference type.
And yes, it is same for both Java and c#